# No advantage to contiguous memory vector when elements are pointers or references?

Tags: c++, list, caching, vector, containers

I've been reading about the different containers in the C++ standard library, and I keep on hearing about how the simple vector in practice will often outperform most of the other containers when iterating over the elements. This is said to be due to the cache coherency (all stored in contiguous memory), instead of jumping around from place to place in a binary tree or linked list. But I was thinking, if we're talking about a vector of pointers or references to objects as opposed to the objects themselves, iterating over the vector will involve a dereference on each iteration, where the object is located in a separate area of memory. In this case I can't see it being any better than jumping from link to link in a list or a tree. The way I see it is like the following, and each one pretty much does the same thing as far as I can see.

[image]

If this is true, then can I assume that whenever people claim that the vector is more cache-friendly that it's ONLY the case when storing objects, and not pointers or references to objects? Also, I don't suppose if the pointers would be to a polymorphic type would make a difference between the two?

Comment: Even for a `vector` of pointers, you still need to read the values of those pointers to dereference them. Getting those addresses will still be more cache-friendly with a `vector` than with a list.

Comment: The vector is more cache friendly than a list if both vector and list store the same data type, which in your illustration the apparently do not. You need to compare like with like.

Comment: "In this case I can't see it being any better than jumping from link to link in a list or a tree" because to access the pointers stored in a list or tree is still less efficient than if they were stored in a vector. Dereferencing that pointers comes on top of that and it doesnt matter where the pointer was coming from

Comment: `std::vector` should always be the default container unless you have very special needs. Then if the "performance" is not "good enough" or up to the stated requirements, you can start measuring and profiling and trying out different containers.

Comment: Just going to the nth element of a vector is going to be a lot more efficient then the nth element of the list.

Comment: @NathanOliver I guess if all you were going to do was just iterate over them all without reading them then the vector would be a lot better.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth Ah good point, the equivalent would be List<Obj*>, not List<Obj> as my diagram shows.

Comment: @Zebrafish My point is going from one vector element to another is faster than going from one node in a list to another.  So, since both would use an indirection to access the value of the element the vector will still be faster.

Comment: @Zebrafish The only means of accessing an element in  a list is to use iteration - this isn't the case for vectors.

Answer (score 1):

```
|ptr1|ptr2|ptr3|ptr4|       //vector
```

and

```
|ptr1|--->|ptr2|--->|ptr3|--->|ptr4|   //list
```

Now consider accessing the third object via `ptr3`.

Time taken by vector.

```
O(1) time to reach ptr3 + time to dereference ptr3
```

Time taken by list

```
O(2) time to reach ptr3 + time to dereference ptr3.
```

So the difference is in reaching the pointer to be dereferenced.

In general accessing an element on a `vector` is O(1) while in a `list` is O(n)

Comment: Yeah I was aware of the whole random access thing. But as Neil Butterworth pointed out my diagram doesn't even show a fair comparison, as the vector is type vector<Obj*> and the list is type list<Obj>.